# Lenovo ThinkCentre TC M700 does not boot - stuck on Lenovo Motherboard Logo

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-desktop-computer, thinkcentre

I got a TC M700 thinkcentre smaller Lenovo desktop computer. When I try to boot, it is stuck on Motherboard logo. No activity of HDD is shown. No beeping signals. It is not possible to enter BIOS settings as well, and get into boot startup sequence. I have tried:

plug - unplug power

plug - unplug battery of BIOS

connect SSD to another computer. Disk is accessible. Tried to boot without disk and did not get a message "boot disk not found". I have tried to boot from USB drive without the computer's main disk, but did not get to OS boot sequence.

tried to boot without memory module. I got sound signals, just had to check beeping component.
place memory module to another slot

Those did not help resolve situation

What may be a reason? Is it a firmware or BIOS?

Comment: Go to the Lenovo Support site for your model, . Find the hardware diagnostics, make a bootable USB key. Start and press F12 repeatedly to boot from the diagnostic USB key. See if that works and test hardware.

Comment: I suffered the same issue with the same model. "Bluetooth device may hang at restart because Wi-Fi (WLAN) device sent an unsupported command to Bluetooth." https://kb.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/HT506393

Answer (score 0):

Many of these laptop manufacturers create boot error codes with beeping or flashing lights. If it is giving you those, you could post it here so we can figure out what is causing an issue.   I had dealt with similar issues at work with dell computers flashing certain codes, most of the time for me it was memory module failure codes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wish there was a sound signal, or any flashing. But... there is no sound signal (beeper works, i tested it, as shown in question). I have not observed any flashing too. Keyboard does not react to input (Scroll Lock, Caps Lock, Num Lock does not change LED state), no indication of disk activity. When I tried to boot from USB, a flash drive did not turn on a LED. Just a screen with Motherboard logo